# Go to a screen on inactivity for a given timeout

Tags: android

I have the situation, where my Android application will have a pre-defined user inactivity timeout say 10mins. I was able to complete this using CountDownTimer and a service. Once the timer finishes the service broadcasts an event. Once I receive an event for the timer finish, I should clear all the activities in the task stack and go to a screen like login screen. Can anyone help with a best possible solution to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Using the count down timer was enough to handle time why a service

Comment: I do have some other tasks in the service, so I added count down to the list.

Comment: But your solution looks okay and perfect to me!

Comment: I have reciever in the activities to listen for timer finish event. What I was thinking to do is to listen for the event and finish the activity. So I was checking if there is a better way of doing the task.

Comment: You do not need any receiver! You should just wait for the time to finish then  start login screen directly from the service!